# How to get data from response to get request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Trying to make get request from node.js with express module. Here is code of this piece:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk){
    });

});
req.end();
```

But can't understand how to receive data from responses body, i tried res.body. or res.data. Didn't work.

Comment: A couple of books that might help you: [1](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/index.html) - [2](http://www.nodebeginner.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data arrives in the `chunk` parameter. Parts of it anyway. You need to pick up and join all the chunks into a complete response. Copy-paste example from http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request:

```
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```